# Convert Delaunay Trinagulation to Volume

Tags: matlab, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to go from a point cloud to a volume (3D cube).

I can get a pretty good representation of the volume by making a delaunay triangulation.

How do I go from the triangulation to a 3D mat?

I'm thinking maybe test a bunch of query points and figure out if they lie inside a triangle/tetrahedron, but I can't figure out the best way to do this:

```
clc; clear all;
% Build a cube, in my target application this going to be from a point cloud
d = [-1 1];
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(d,d,d); % a cube
x = [x(:);0];
y = [y(:);0];
z = [z(:);0];
DT = delaunayTriangulation(x,y,z);
V=ones(size(x),'like',x);
%Build a volume from these points?
n=5;samples=linspace(-2,2);
[xq,yq,zq]=meshgrid(samples,samples,samples);
pq=[xq(:),yq(:),zq(:)];
vi = nearestNeighbor(DT,pq);
res=reshape(vi,size(xq));
%As expected, edges are messed up, not a cube...
imagesc(res(:,:,round(end/2)));
% %tetramesh(DT);
```

Comment: I am confused. If it is a cube, then you don't care if its a delaunay triangulation or not, its just a cube. Knowing if a point is inside a cube its a 3 logical operation, you can do it in 1 line. If instead, the  boundary of your triangulation is arbitrarily shaped, then your proposed solution does not make sense. Not really sure what is the case here

Comment: @AnderBiguri In my target application its not a cube. Its an arbitrary 3D triangulation.

Comment: Fair, then possibly your solution is indeed the best solution.

Comment: With the best of my effort, I can't make any sense of your question. 2D ? 3D ? Triangulation ? Tetrahedization ? Hull ? Boundary model ? Voxels ???

Comment: @Mikhail: thank you for the optimal understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
vi = nearestNeighbor(DT,pq);
```

could be

```
vi = pointLocation(DT,pq);
```

This returns nan when the point isn't enclosed:

Anyways, leaving this open for a while because I'm not sure my solution is optimal.

Also this is somewhat computationally intensive.